# get user data from list of uids - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of UIDs and I need to get the user name and PhotoURL for each user id that is inside that list. when I try to do it with a for loop I'm only getting the data for the first uid. how can I do this properly?

```
  Future<List<UserModel>> getUserDetailsById(List ids) async {
try {
  List<UserModel> users = [];
  for (var id in ids) {
    final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(id).get();
    users.add(UserModel.fromMap(id, documentSnapshot.data()));
    return users;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  return [];
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` in a for loop will return you from the function

remove it from loop and add it after

```
Future<List<UserModel>> getUserDetailsById(List ids) async {
try {
  List<UserModel> users = [];
  for (var id in ids) {
    final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(id).get();
    users.add(UserModel.fromMap(id, documentSnapshot.data()));
  }
 return users;
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  return [];
   }
}
```